# Destroy a deactivated object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I want simply to destroy a deactivated instance of a Quad prefab (hp bar) , am able to destroy activated ones with :

```
private GameObject correspondingHpBar; 
private string correspondingHpBarName;

void Start() 
{ 
    correspondingHpBarName = "hpBar1" 
}

void Update()
{
    correspondingHpBar = GameObject.Find (correspondingHpBarName); 
    if (shipHp <= 0)
    {
        Destroy (correspondingHpBar); 
        Destroy (gameObject); 
    }
}
```

This doesn't work with the deactivated objects, i googled hard but failed to find an answer.

Comment: If you are using the Unity game engine please add the tag [tag:unity3d] (even for 2d games), if you are not using Unity please find the tag for whatever engine you are using. Also "It doesn't work" is not enough information, [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30537521/edit) and explain how it does not work. Do you get a exception? does it not behave in the expected way?

Answer (score 0):

Deactivated object don't have their `Start` or `Update` method called (nor any coroutine for that matter). In fact when an object is deactivated it is like its own time is frozen.

What you could do is create a method that does the destruction and find a way to call it from another script (for example a kind of controller that keeps reference to all HP bars in your scene).

The following is some pseudo-code (didn't check if it compiles, but you should adapt it anyway):

```
// in script for HP bar
public Boolean TryDestroy()
{
    if (shipHp <= 0)
    {
        Destroy (correspondingHpBar); 
        Destroy (gameObject); 
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// in another script
private List<HPBar> _allHPBars;
void Awake()
{
    _allHPBars = new List<HPBar>(FindObjectsOfType(typeof(HPBar)));
}

void Update()
{
    var destroyedHPBars = new List<HPBar>();
    foreach (var hpBar in _allHPBars)
    {
        if (hpBar.TryDestroy())
        {
            destroyedHPBars .Add(hpBar);
        }
    }
    foreach (var destroyedBar in destroyedHPBars)
    {
        _allHPBars.Remove(destroyedBar);
    }
}
```